# Postgres: Failed system call was shmget(key=3879116, size=56, 03600)

Tags: macos, postgresql

I recently upgraded from a 2013 Macbook Pro to an M1 iMac 2021. This was done using the data stored in Time Machine by my old Macbook. The old Macbook had no problems, ever, running Postgres. But then as I'm finishing up setting up my new mac and ready to start up my development environment Postgres starts failing to startup.

When I try to use `brew services start postgresql` it reports that it was successful. But then when I try to `psql` into it, it fails. After checking the log the specific error is:

> 2022-05-20 21:47:03.244 MST [48487] FATAL:  could not create shared memory segment: Cannot allocate memory
> 2022-05-20 21:47:03.244 MST [48487] DETAIL:  Failed system call was shmget(key=1559810, size=56, 03600).
> 2022-05-20 21:47:03.244 MST [48487] HINT:  This error usually means that PostgreSQL's request for a shared memory segment exceeded your kernel's SHMALL parameter.  You might need to reconfigure the kernel with larger SHMALL.
> The PostgreSQL documentation contains more information about shared memory configuration.

On my system `kern.sysv.shmax` is 4194304 and `kern.sysv.schmall` is 1024. Ironically, I checked my old Macbook and those were the exact same values for those two variables on there as well. Which is the first sign that something went wrong during the data transfer from the old to the new mac. The second sign was the sparse posts on Stack Exchange sites regarding this issue in the context of local development environments. Then the third sign is that in almost all the errors I've seen referenced, the "size" parameter in the error was greater than the `shmall` parameter (03600).

I'm wondering if anyone has any insight as to a source of this problem other than the system variable values. For example, why would 1024 for the `shmall` parameter be A-OK on the old macbook pro, but then when the same PostgreSQL instance is ran — taken from the Time Machine image — on the new Mac, it suddenly requires a larger `shmall` value. Then, Postgres is a pretty popular database, and the new M1's are pretty popular, so you'd think that if this was a product of spinning the instance on a newer mac then there'd be more recent activity on Stack Exchange sites regarding it, but there hasn't appeared to be.

This leads me to believe that this issue is a product of a mistake made during the migration process to the new mac rather than an issue with the current values of those variables. Which would mean changing the values to something Postgres is currently expecting wouldn't address the root of the issue. Which is what I'm trying to do here.

Is it possible that this error could be thrown by Postgres if too much RAM was taken by open applications — I thought that was the whole point of the swap?

Comment: Try with a larger `SHMALL` ; remember that it's measured in pages, not bytes.